# Dynamic Textboxes and passing their value to a Map<String,Map<String,String>

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable

I have a 3D data-table, so in this table I generate the  dynamically.Now I want to pass the value of the row,column and the textbox to a Map
I am stuck with it and it is kind of hard for me to bind the JSF textbox with the backbean.
If someone can please help me with this? a cod example will be great :)
Thanks in Advance:

```
<p:dataTable var="colName" value="#{createEntry.colls}"
    rowIndexVar="colIdx">

    <p:column headerText="Activity" styleClass="ui-widget-header">

        <h:outputText value="#{colName}" binding="#{createEntry.timeEntryAdd.key}" />

    </p:column>

    <p:columns var="rowName" value="#{createEntry.rowws}"
        headerText="#{rowName}" columnIndexVar="rowIdx" binding="#{createEntry.timeEntryAdd.workDate}">

        <h:form id="textBoxesForm" >



                <ui:repeat value="#{createEntry.data3D[rowIdx][colIdx]}" var="data"  >
                    <p:panel>
                    <p:inputText id="text" value="#{data}"  style="width:30px;" >

                    </p:inputText>
                    </p:panel>
                    <h:commandButton value="btn" action="#{createEntry.printko(rowName)}" />

            <!-- <input type="text" name="#{rowIdx}#{colIdx}" value="#{data}" style="width:30px;" />-->

            </ui:repeat>


        </h:form>

    </p:columns>
</p:dataTable>

        <h:form>
            <p:commandButton value="Submit" style="margin-left:710px;" action="#{createEntry.printko(createEntry.data3D[0][1])}" ajax="false" process=":textBoxesForm">
            </p:commandButton>
        </h:form>
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. You need to illustrate better what you're trying to achieve and what your data stucture looks like. Also, that `<h:form/>` you have inside the table will result in nested `<h:form/>`s (I'm assuming the datatable itself is in a `<h:form/>`), a major no-no

Comment: So the problem is that, I have this data table, it contains:

Heading: with dates
Then Activity Name:
Then The Data, which will have textboxes to be filled.
so now what I want to do is, I want to fill the textboxes and when I press the submit button, the form should be passed to a function, that processes, the textbox value, with the date and activityname.

and it is giving me hard time, thanks for the help in advance.